# Proving $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology

It is straightforward to prove using a connectedness argument that $\mathbb{R}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, for $n>1$.

How do you prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Note: I'm looking for a proof which does not use any algebraic topology,not even Brouwer's fixed point theorem. [I know that there are proofs of Brouwer's theorem using purely analytic methods, but I still do not want to include it - I'm looking for something even simpler]

Me and a few friends have been at this for a couple of weeks, but kept running in circles. Unfortunately, this was a long time ago, and I have completely forgotten what we tried. Any ideas?

---

Edit: Thanks for all the answers, but I still didn't get what I was looking for. I should have been more explicit : I don't want to use the Jordan curve theorem either. (The simplest proof of that which I've seen involves Brouwer's fixed point theorem). I'm looking for a proof which does not use anything apart from ideas of connectedness and compactness.

Looking at the answers, a second question came to my mind: Given that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$, can you deduce the Jordan curve theorem?

Comment: A circle doesn't disconnect $\mathbb{R}^3$, while it disconnects $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I think one can also take the $x$-axis, which disconnects $\Bbb R^2$, but its image does not disconnect $\Bbb R^3$. But how elementary is it to prove that such a line keeps the space connected @egreg?

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314777/show-that-using-jordan-curve-theorem-mathbbr2-is-not-homeomorphic-to-mat/314782#314782) is a proof using the Jordan Curve Theorem.

Comment: @StefanH. For a closed curve it's not elementary, because Jordan's theorem is quite difficult to prove. Unfortunately no simple method seems to apply; for the line and the plane two points suffice.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. Do you know how easy a prove using an axis in $R^2$ and its image in $R^3$ would be?

Comment: @egreg how do you prove that the image of a circle doesn't disconnect $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: @Amudhan I'd do the reverse; the complement of a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is connected, while its image in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the supposed homeomorphism is the complement of a closed curve, which is disconnected.

Comment: @egreg but this would mean using the Jordan curve theorem...

Comment: @Amudhan Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A elementary proof can be found in the following [article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1467v2.pdf):

*An interesting proof on the nonexistence of a continuous function between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n \neq 2$*, by F. Malek, H. Daneshpajouh, H.R. Daneshpajouh and J. Hahn.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ any closed curve has an outside and an inside (Jordan curve theorem), but in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what happens then?

Comment: This is the same idea as the method using the Jordan curve theorem as in the link given by Alex Becker.